# Answer key for German Second and Third Years

Tags: resource-request, english

I am retired and returning to my former (undergraduate) study of German.  Currently I am beginning *German Second and Third Years* by Harry F. Reinert and Walter Kleinmann, Revised Edition (1994  ISBN 978-0-87720-577-7).  I would very much like to get an answer key.

I have done a Google search and only came up with a digital one on Amazon which required that it be purchased for delivery to a school address.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The only location where I could find a answer key is on [Perfection Learning](https://www.perfectionlearning.com/german-second-and-third-years-13523-g.html), which offers both the workbook and the answer key. I don't know whether delivery requires a specific type of address.

I could not find an answer key in [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=ti%3Ati%3AGerman+Second+and+Third+Years+au%3AReinert&qt=notfound_page&search=Search); only the workbook is listed in the catalogue.

Comment: Thank you so much - but why did you mess with my question - there is nothing amiss with it?

Comment: @Linda We tend to edit out whatever is not relevant to the question. I also thought adding the names of the authors would improve it.

Comment: Oh...          By the way, Perfection Learning is the same source as I found and they only ship the key to a school address with a book order for a class.